# Wi Fi issue on the Pi 3

Tags: wifi, wireless

I was able to connect to Wi-Fi easily at home. However, when I tried to connect over someone else's house, I chose the name of their Wi-Fi router & put in the correct password for their Wi-Fi & nothing happened. It simply would not connect. I tried updating & upgrading the Pi 3 but that did not help.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Unless you tell us about the network we can't help. `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` is good advice to find this. Many people still use WEP and this can't be configured by the GUI tool.

Comment: I tried switching to wpa & that did not work

Comment: I will run the sudo iwlist wlan0 scan & get back to you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt would be to list all available hotspots. This can be done via

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`

When you can see the hotspot you want to connect check if the provider uses DHCP or static IP addresses and if it matches your configuration.

The last thing I can think of would be the usage of hidden SSIDs. Then you have to include 2 settings.

Just to check - here is the configuration that I use:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-scan-ssid 1
wpa-ssid "name of hotspot"
wpa-psk "password"
```

One more thing: if the authentication is not WPA or WPA2 you have to specify it as well. I think this case is rather obscure. You can see the authentication in the result of the scan.

Comment: The "configuration that I use" may work for you (by good luck) BUT  is poor practice and not robust. You can continue to use `dhcp` if you wish but others should follow the recommended Foundation practice.

Comment: This is what I got when I check for hot spots.

Comment: Cell 01 - Address: 90:3E:AB:40:B4:A0
Channel:11
Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"ATT576"
Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
Mode:Master
Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
Extra: Last beacon: 70ms ago
IE: Unknown: 0006415454353736
IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
IE: Unknown: 03010B
IE: Unknown: 050402030000
IE: Unknown: 2A0100
IE: Unknown: 2F0100
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : TKIP
Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP

Comment: Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
IE: Unknown: 2D1A7C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
IE: Unknown: 3D160B081500000000000000000000000000000000000000
IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
IE: Unknown: 7F0101
IE: Unknown: DD090010180202F02C0000
IE: WPA Version 1
Group Cipher : TKIP
Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00